# Getting magnetic north from a xyz magnetometer (iPhone 3.0)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, magnetometer

I'm actually reposting a question from the iphone development boards.  I didn't ask it, but I found it when trying to find its answer.  Nobody had yet responded there, so I thought I'd try posting it here.

### Thanks in advance for any help!

Does anybody know any specifics about the algorithm of computing the magnetic heading from the raw xyz values of CLHeading?  I am sure there must be a general approach to this that works for different magnetometers as well.

Comment: [Implementing a Tilt-Compensated eCompass using Accelerometer and Magnetometer Sensors](http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4248.pdf) - "This technical note provides the mathematics, reference 
source code and guidance for engineers implementing a 
tilt-compensated electronic compass (eCompass)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `trueHeading` value, and assuming that the compass lies perfectly horizontal, the heading can be computed this way:

- (y>0) heading = 90 - atan2(x,y)*180 / pi
- (y<0) heading = 270 - atan2(x,y)*180 / pi
- (y=0, x<0) heading = 180.0
- (y=0, x>0) heading = 0.0

(these are from http://www.magneticsensors.com/datasheets/an203.pdf)

... plus the heading must be corrected for [Magnetic deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_deviation) and [Magnetic declination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination)

in case the compass is not horizontal, you should use only the horizontal component (you can not ignore the z axis) by projecting the (x, y, z) vector to a plane that is parallel to the earth surface and then compute the heading from this projected x and y.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note in the above the divide by pi is missing and apple and Honeywell's x and y definitions are opposite.